# Avoiding Postbacks in ontextchange event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a `asp:textbox` and it is firing ontextchanged event, and in that event I am binding the value to a session variable. My problem is that it postsback the page everytime, so I want to avoid the postback in that event.

Please assist me in doing the same.

Comment: ontextchange is a postback event when you set AutoPostBack="True". What are you trying to achieve? Is achieve without calling code in the code-behind?

Comment: I think you should write your requirement more clearly..what you want to achieve and what you are doing for that...

Answer (score 1):

`OnTextChanged` is a server event and if you want it fired and your session state updated correctly then the page needs to undergo a postback. Another approach is to use `onchange` which is a client event and to update your session state via `javascript` performing an ajax call to your back-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the event on the Client-Side (JavaScript) then you should use `onchange`.

Now it is handled on the Server-Side because of OnTextChange is part of the `asp:TextBox` and is a server side event. Basicly Server-Side events = postback